# Insert Heading, One Level Above

Tags: org-mode

I want to insert a heading above the current level, like org-insert-superheading

I've found a few references, but for vi mode

Any pointers?;)

Comment: Would `M-RET M-<left>` (Alt+Enter, Alt+left-arrow) do?

Comment: It very much depends on where you are exactly, but try some combinations from the Org mode "Navigate Headings" menu. @dalanicolai's suggestion is one possibility, but there are many others as well.

Comment: I'd like a custom function for this, so that I can bind a keyboard combination to it;) M-RET M-LEFT is too cumbersome and I use this a lot